# Terraria server map location

Tags: terraria

When you join a server, where dose the downloaded server map go in Terr aria?

I've looked all over for it.

Comment: I doubt it actually downloads the map, probably just streams the current state to memory

Answer (score 4):

The maps aren't actually downloaded as a regular Terraria map file like those for your local games and your own server at Documents\My Games\Terraria; instead they are kept in memory and are probably incomplete because of the limits of bandwidth. This data only exists temporarily in your  computer's RAM, which is cleared when you exit the game or power down your PC.